# How to check if the last characters in an array meet a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, substring

I am trying to remove the last characters of an element in an array only if they meet a condition. For example: if they end in s, then I remove the s. If not, the element should remain the same.
This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
let myList = []
for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
        if (arrays[i].substring(arrays[i].length - 1) == 's'){
        item = arrays[i].slice(0,-1);
        myList.push(item);
        }else{
            myList.push(arrays[i]);
        }
```

It's not working though, and idea why?

Comment: Can you add some input, and your expected output, as a [mcve], please. You can use the `[<>]` option in the edit window to create a snippet.

Comment: Please see [How do I chop/slice/trim off last character in string using Javascript?](/a/61786227/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

this way

```js
const 
  arr    = ['Johns','Paul', 'ringos', 'Georges']
, myList = arr.map( name => /s$/.test(name) ? name.slice(0, -1) : name)
  ;

console.log( myList )
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) `s` then you can [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) it as:

```js
const arr = ["Johns", "Paul", "ringos", "Georges"];
const myList = arr.map(name => name.endsWith("s") ? name.slice(0, -1) : name);
console.log(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have write, it seems it lacks `}`.  And if you wonder why nothing happen in the terminal, it's because you have not write `console.log(myList)` in your code.
This code should works:

```js
const arrays = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas', 'Pear']
let myList = []
for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
        if (arrays[i].substring(arrays[i].length - 1) == 's') {
        item = arrays[i].slice(0,-1);
        myList.push(item);
        } else {
            myList.push(arrays[i]);
        }
    }

console.log("List:", myList)
```